# Characters and Numbers behave differently when , vertical align centre inside input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am using some input fields in my project for a reset password functionality .  I want my input values vertically aligned inside my input fields .

1. When I correctly aligned numeric values inside input, the character values are not aligned correctly. like this .

[image]

My CSS for input in this case

```
width: 50px;
height: 48px;
border: 1px solid #58595b;
border-radius: 100%;
font-size: 40px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
text-align: center;
```

2. When I correctly aligned character values inside input , the numeric values are not aligned correctly . like this .

[image]

My CSS for input in this case

```
width: 50px;
height: 43px;
border: 1px solid #58595b;
border-radius: 100%;
font-size: 40px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
text-align: center;
```

I am trying to change `height` and `padding-bottom`  in these cases.

**My Question**

How can I vertical align center both numeric and character values at the same time . I am being stuck for some time in this situation . Please help . thanks in advance .

** I have tested in Both Safari and Chrome.

Here is The jsFiddle Link -> https://jsfiddle.net/qzrf4dnb/2/

Comment: What is your full HTML and CSS?

Comment: add a fiddle example to see your problem live.i think there are some typefaces those have same height for numbers and chars

Comment: Nothing much input field is like <input type="text" maxlength="1" />

Comment: @FastSnail https://jsfiddle.net/qzrf4dnb/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add another class for lower-case letters with a different -less- number of `line-height` like this:

**[jsFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/fzftju0o/)**

```css
.circle-div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: skyblue;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.lower-case {
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-div lower-case">c</div>
<div class="circle-div">9</div>
<div class="circle-div">A</div>
```

---

**Update 1:**

Considering the case of input field, the above wouldn't work because it wouldn't be affected by the value of `line-height`, but following the same way of making use of another class for such special case, we can fine tune the values of `padding` and `height`, just like this:

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/fzftju0o/3/)

```css
.circle-input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px #888 solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.lower-case {
  height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="circle-input lower-case" maxlength="1" value="c">
<input type="text" class="circle-input" maxlength="1" value="9">
<input type="text" class="circle-input" maxlength="1" value="A">
```

---

**Update 2:**

Mostly you would want to make this dynamic, you need to check each input value with javascript when page first load or upon input or change events, this could be achieved like this:

[**jsFiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/fzftju0o/4/)

```js
var circleInputs = $('.circle-input');

circleInputs.each(function() {
  checkLowerCase($(this), $(this).val());
});

circleInputs.on('change input', function() {
  checkLowerCase($(this), $(this).val());
});

function checkLowerCase(item, value) {
  if ((/[a-z]/).test(value)) {
    item.addClass('lower-case');
  } else {
    item.removeClass('lower-case');
  }
}
```

```css
.circle-input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px #888 solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.lower-case {
  height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="circle-input" maxlength="1" value="c">
<input type="text" class="circle-input" maxlength="1" value="9">
<input type="text" class="circle-input" maxlength="1" value="A">
```

Comment: Hi For Div it seems ok , But i tried your code with input fields and seems not working . can you please  try with input fields ?

Comment: Sure, for input fields it needs to be `height` and `padding` values rather than `line-height`, check this https://jsfiddle.net/fzftju0o/1/

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya please check my updated answer, now this is all automated and dynamic with jQuery

Comment: Great Thanks . I will check this , give me some time :) :) , Thank you for your kind support

Answer (score 1):

Good question! I don't believe this is possible for arbitrary characters, without coding specific values for each character. The line-height=container-height trick will effectively vertically align a *line* of text in a container, but not a single character. The reason is that the characters have different heights, but they all sit on more or less the same baseline (except for characters that sit below it like **g** or **y**). One thing you can do is force your users to use only capital letters, (via the css `text-transform:uppercase;`) which will likely all be more or less the same height as each other, and numbers.

```css
div.round {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class='round'>a</div>
<div class='round'>9</div>
<div class='round'>c</div>
<div class='round'>7</div>
<br /> vs <br />
<div class='round upper'>a</div>
<div class='round upper'>9</div>
<div class='round upper'>c</div>
<div class='round upper'>7</div>
```

Sorry this doesn't exactly answer the question. They aren't centered perfectly, but they look more centered then the lowercase version.

Answer (score -2):

`margin: auto;
height=width
comment padding-bottom`

I think

Comment: Do you mean that `height` and `width` should be set to equal values, and that `padding-bottom` should be commented out? Please clarify your answer; someone has already flagged it for deletion due to the poor quality.